# Tutorials and resources on jqgrid and flexigrid

Tags: zend-framework, jqgrid, flexigrid

Am currently trying to use for *the first time* both jqgrid and flexigrid to make database driven pages whos backend uses Zend Framework.
I have been googling and the search results that turn up aren't very helpful.
Any links that can be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm not fammiliar with the Zend framework, but as per a useful link for jqGrid documentation I find [this wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs) to be the best.

**Edit:** This is also a valid documentation resource [here](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm).

Comment: Agreed. Also, the main jqGrid site ( http://www.trirand.com/blog/ ) has a lot of demos that are useful for putting together those first few grids...

Comment: Thanks Mike.The second link you provided was more informative than the first

Comment: Keep in mind the second link contains old documentation that does not include jqGrid 3.5. That information is probably fine for the moment, but it will grow more obsolete over time...

Answer (score 0):

The [Demo page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) on the official jqGrid site provides a lot of good examples and the code behind them.

Well worth checking out as it covers most things you can do with it.